# Getting the value from pgSQL INSERT..ON CONFLICT RETURNING in PHP PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Two capabilities of pgSQL that I use quite frequently are `INSERT... ON CONFLICT` AND `INSERT... RETURNING`.  However it is not clear to me how I combine these two capabilities when working in PHP PDO.  Here is an example.

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE symbols ("id" integer DEFAULT nextval('symbols_id_seq') NOT NULL,
 "atom" character varying(32) NOT NULL,
 "attime" smallint NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "symbols_atom_key" UNIQUE ("atom")
) WITH (oids = false);
```

In my server side script I have the following

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO symbols (atom,attime) VALUES(?,?) ON CONFLICT(atom) DO UPDATE SET attime = ? RETURNING id");
```

No problems thus far.  I can, for instance, issue

```
$stmt->execute(array('chocolate',1,-1));
```

However, all that `PDOStatement->execute` returns is a boolean representing success or failure.  What happens to the returned id value and how can I get at it?